# In mdn web docs Element.querySelector method says that it should be descendant but example shows otherwise

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

I am learning JavaScript from the MDN web docs. I was studying `Element.querySelector()` method.

It is written that it returns the first element that is a descendant of the element on which it is invoked that matches the specified group of selectors.

But there is an example given, which contradicts this fact.

```js
var baseElement = document.querySelector("p");
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
  (baseElement.querySelector("div span").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
  <h5>Original content</h5>
  <p>
    inside paragraph
    <span>inside span</span>
    inside paragraph
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>Output</h5>
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

Here, `div` tag is not a descendant of `p` tag, still this code works.

Can you point where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element.querySelector()` first applies the CSS Selectors passed to `.querySelector()` method, **on the whole document** and **not the base element** on which `.querySelector()` was invoked. This is done to generate initial set of potential elements.

After generating initial set of potential elements, list of potential elements is then filtered to retain only those elements which are descendants of the base element. Finally, the first element from this filtered list is returned.

---

In your code example, entire document is first searched for elements that match `div span`. As there is only one element in the entire document that matches `div span` selector, initial set of potential elements contains only one `span` element. After that, this `span` element is checked to see if it is the descendant of `baseElement`. Since, in this case, it is a descendant of
the `baseElement`, it is returned.

---

What i explained above is written under "Return Value" heading in [MDN - Element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

> The entire hierarchy of elements is
> considered when matching, including those outside the set of elements
> including baseElement and its descendants; in other words, selectors
> is first applied to the whole document, not the baseElement, to
> generate an initial list of potential elements. The resulting elements
> are then examined to see if they are descendants of baseElement. The
> first match of those remaining elements is returned by the
> querySelector() method.

Answer (score 0):

In the MDN example, the selector term `div span` returns the first `span` with a `div` ancestor that is within the selector's element, even if the ancestor `div` itself is *not* within the element.

In general, only the last element in the selector path *must* be within the selector's element, as long as its path matches the selector's.

This is why they say to prefix the selector term with `:scope` to ensure that *all* elements on the selector's path *must* be within the selector's element.