# What is the difference between calling the DOM method appendChild directly on document.body versus first using queryselector

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there any difference to calling the following which both result in the same output?

```
// direct call
      const p = document.createElement('p')
      p.innerHtml = 'I am a p tag' 
      document.body.appendChild(p)

// first querySelector then method call
      const p = document.createElement('p')
      p.innerHtml = 'I am a p tag' 
      const body = document.querySelector('body')
      body.appendChild(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no functional difference since both approaches to access the body return the same object. From a performance stand point `document.body` is most likely faster but I highly doubt the difference is significant enough to suggest not using querySelector

There are numerous ways to access the same dom element

```js
const el = document.querySelector('body')

console.log(el === document.body) //true
console.log(el === document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) // true
```

Comment: I imagine there's some difference between accessing the body using `document.body` and using `document.querySelector('body')` because of how [`querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873962/in-mdn-web-docs-element-queryselector-method-says-that-it-should-be-descendant-b/62874198#62874198?utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=ZEEF&utm_source=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-useful-stackoverflow-answers.zeef.com%2Fyousaf.khan) works BUT i am not sure whether there's a different between `document.querySelector()` and `Element.querySelector()`.

Comment: Performance wise `document.body` should be fastest since it's a single property on document. Not really sure what sort of answer you were looking for. Should be no unexpected side effects using either approach if that's your concern

Comment: _Performance wise document.body should be fastest since it's a single property on document_ - Yes, that is what i think OP wants to know and would be nice if you mention this in your answer. Functionally they both are same but there's a difference performance wise. I was typing the answer but you did so before me so i decided against answering myself.

Comment: @Yousaf the difference though wouldn't be very significant.

Comment: You are right but still the difference is what OP wants to know.